# TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python, I tried to use filter2D function but I get this error.

img_out = cv2.filter2D(img_in,-1,cv2.UMat(gb));
TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found ... what does this mean?

```
      import numpy as np
      import cv2


      def gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma):
      sigma_x = sigma
      sigma_y = float(sigma) / gamma

      # Bounding box
      nstds = 3  # Number of standard deviation sigma
      xmax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.cos(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.sin(theta)))
      xmax = np.ceil(max(1, xmax))
      ymax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.sin(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.cos(theta)))
      ymax = np.ceil(max(1, ymax))
      xmin = -xmax
      ymin = -ymax
      (y, x) = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ymin, ymax + 1), np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1))

      x_theta = x * np.cos(theta) + y * np.sin(theta)
      y_theta = -x * np.sin(theta) + y * np.cos(theta)

      gb = np.exp(-0.5 * (np.power(x_theta, 2) / np.add(np.power(sigma_x, 2) , np.power(y_theta, 2)) / np.power(sigma_y, 2)* np.cos(2 * np.pi / Lambda * x_theta + psi[0])));

      return gb;


   Lambda = 8;
   theta = 0;
   psi = [0, np.pi / 2];
   gamma = 0.5;
   sigma = 1.0;
   N = 8;
   img_in = cv2.imread('1.jpg');
   img_in = cv2.cvtColor(img_in, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

   for n in range(N):
     gb = np.add(gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma) , 1j * 
     gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma));
     img_out = cv2.filter2D(img_in,-1,cv2.UMat(gb));
     theta = theta + (2 * np.pi) / N

   img_out_disp = np.power(sum(np.power(abs(img_out), 2), 3), 0.5);
   img_out_disp = np.divide(img_out_disp, max(img_out_disp));
```

Comment: Why are you casting as a `UMat`?

Comment: because I got this error before casting it ... TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'kernel'

Comment: You need to pass a numpy array as the kernel.

Comment: I want to pass a gabor kernel in the kernel argument because I'm trying to implement gabor filter. Do I pass it in a wrong syntax?

    gb = np.add(gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma) , 1j * 
    gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma));

    img_out = cv2.filter2D(img_in,-1,gb);

Comment: What is `gabor_fn`? Also please add code into an edit to your OP, not in comments.

Comment: gabor_fn is gabor function that returns gabor kernels that will be convoluted with the input image, I added the code to the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convolve with a complex kernel with OpenCV's `filter2D()`. The [docs for `filter2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) specify that the kernel must be a "single-channel floating point matrix."

To use OpenCV's functions, you'll have to convolve the real and imaginary portions of the kernels separately and combine the results how you wish.

Scipy is another option if you're using Python, which does directly support complex convolution. The [docs for `scipy.signal.convolve2d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) shows an example with a complex Scharr filter.

For future reference, with OpenCV you can directly get a Gabor kernel via the function [`getGaborFilter()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gae84c92d248183bd92fa713ce51cc3599) instead of computing it yourself, though note it only returns the real part.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked with the "getGaborFilter()".

Answer (score 1):

it means the function you want to use expects an argument called 'ranges' in the 2nd position.

However, I'm not sure this is a `filter2D` error as this is the function's [declaration](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20filter2D(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20InputArray%20kernel,%20Point%20anchor,%20double%20delta,%20int%20borderType)):

```
Python: cv2.filter2D(src, ddepth, kernel[, dst[, anchor[, delta[, borderType]]]]) → dst¶
```

and as you can see - no 'ranges' required here...
there probably is another function that does require 'ranges' argument that is not provided.

Comment: I'm trying to make a convolution between gabor kernels and an input image and that's the code. there're no 'ranges' required in 'gabor_fn'. do you know how can  I the problem please?
for n in range(N):
    gb = np.add(gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma) , 1j * 
    gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma));
    
    img_out = cv2.filter2D(img_in,-1,gb);

    theta = theta + (2 * np.pi) / N;

Comment: TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found

Comment: img_out = cv2.filter2D(img_in,-1,cv2.UMat(gb));
on this line